# How to expose desktop application service in web site ( ASP.NET ) ?

Tags: asp.net

I have no experience in ASP or in web developing.

I wrote some desktop application ( C# .NET4.0 )that simple go to some data source ( like database ) and show the information that this data source hold ( according to some input ).

( on the desktop application the GUI work in MVVM )

I want to use this application and show the data on some web page. 
The application input is some string - so i also want to 'give' this input from this same web page.

So from what i know .. i need to 'put' my application on some server and expose some new interface that have 'web abilities'

Is it right ? 
How to to it ?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its better you create another layer before starting your website

You will have two layers

1. **Service Layer** - Which will connect to database and your application, This can be a plain ASP.NET webservice or WCF(I recommend this). This will take input from your user interface layer, and do operations on database and give appropriate response back to user interface layer
2. **User Interface Layer** - Here you user application will come, this can be a web application, desktop application, mobile application

> Your user interface never connects to your database directly, It will call a service method which you have already created for any database operations
>
> *In starting it is Bit extra work, But it will reduce lot of work in future.*

Following are some links which might help you to get started:

http://www.asp.net/web-api

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t745kdsh(v=vs.90).aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734712.aspx

Answer (score 1):

you have two options you can consume the application in the new web application you are building or develop a new web service hosting the services and consumed by many application. choice is yours

Comment: but i don't need to use any DTO to 'give' the web application the data from the desktop application - right ? because the data is not something that go thru the web --

Comment: I have no idea about the data flow; applications are developed to perform on request that is the data to the application. I guess we need to understand the scope before providing further solution.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use web service to achieve this goal.

Comment: but why i need web service to this goal ? i just need to know how to create show this data on web site ( as i said ... I have no experience in ASP or in web developing ... so there is something i don't understand here )

Comment: Ha, do you mean that i need to expose some WCF service that will bring me up the data ( as TDO ) and the web site will show the data on the Web page ?

Comment: You can consume the same desktop application as an application extension in your web application to show the data.

Comment: yes..you can choose WCF or Web Service for remote interoperability...once you learnt this topic,you will find the solution by yourself...